# Mousewheel scroll to div

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor, onscroll

I want to make this scroll to view effect (link: http://www.phasesmag.com)
, but I have no idea how to do that. My guess is some sections are with id's and when I scroll mouse wheel they are triggered. I have no script to show, because I really don't know where to start. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't know where to start but have an example, always look at the page source. Try to find the javascript files that run the site.

By looking at their main.js I could easily find that they are using the [fullscreen jquery plugin](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage)

By following their guidelines, you should now be able to create your own effect.